# Not getting expected results when I merge 2 pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge 2 pandas data frames via a left join.

FYI, I could not get the table to format properly so please understand I tried.

Left table (265 rows) and many more columns:
I am expecting to end up with 265 rows.

```
Index     ACCSNM   Reason Not Done

260  YA42816-011       IFFREAS29
261  YA42816-011       EMFREAS1
262  YA42816-011       EMFREAS2
263  YA42816-011       EMFREAS3
264  YA42816-011       EMFREAS4
```

Right Table (250 rows):

```
Index    ACCSNM    RND_COLUMNS     MIREASND
245  YA42816-011    IFFREAS7             
246  YA42816-011    IFFREAS6             
247  YA42816-011    IFFREAS5             
248  YA42816-011    IFFREAS3             
249  YA42816-011    EMFREAS4  EM Not done
```

Here is the code I used to merge df's:

```
pd.merge(ln_sdtm, rnd_melt, left_on=["ACCSNM", "Reason Not Done"], right_on=["ACCSNM", 
"MIREASND"],  how="left",  suffixes = (None, '_R')).sort_values(["ACCSNM", "Row 
Number"]).reset_index()
```

I end up with 774 rows and many NaN's in the Reason not done and MIREASND columns.

You're help is much appreciated as I'm on a major deadline with this.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.  I was using the wrong column.

```
pd.merge(ln_sdtm, rnd_melt, left_on=["ACCSNM", "Reason Not Done"], right_on= 
["ACCSNM", 
"RND_COLUMN"],  how="left",  suffixes = (None, '_R')).sort_values(["ACCSNM", 
"Row Number"]).reset_index()
```